# OmniFlow - Preferred Agent - Fallback queue

Tags: visual-workflow, omnichannel, agentwork, queue-based-routing

In our environment we have a combination of skills based and queue based routing, we are now introducing Preferred agent to work in conjuction with the queue based routing. However, we have an issue with the OmniFlow where if we have a Routing configuration rule specified on the queue and also an OmniFlow that tries to route to the preferred agent, then we get both processes assigning the work out leading to duplication and confusion.

So far I've tried to remove the Omni routing configuration from the queue and let the OmniFlow do all of this but then this error is returned:
The queue must be an Omni-Channel queue This Route Work invocable action did not create a valid Pending Service Routing.

Which makes sense, however, I'm unclear how I can make a queue that is routable without it trying to distribute the work to agents outside of the omniflow.
Here is a portion of the flow:
[image: Flow Portion]

Route to Agent portion:
[image: Agent routing]

This is the queue routing:
[image: Routing config]